# Given cluster of documents, compute similarity between corpus and the cluster

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nltk, tf-idf

I am doing a similarity ranking job by computing the distance between each document in the corpus and the cluster. The cluster is also given as list of documents. What I am in trouble with is that I cannot come up with **a proper way of computing the centroid of the cluster** so that I can compute the similarity. I tried to use the average value of tfidf matrix of cluster while it gives poor result.

For example: my cluster is:

```
['Line a baking pan with a sheet of parchment paper.',
 'Line the cake pan with parchment paper.',
 'Line the bottom with parchment paper.',
 'Line a baking pan with parchment paper.'
]
```

And my courpus contains following 3 documents:

```
['Add vinegar and sugar.',
 'Remove pan from heat and let stand 5 minutes.',
 'Line the pan with parchment paper.'
]
```

I want to compute the similarity between every document and the cluster, which might produce result like:

```
[0.1, 0.1, 0.8]
```

Do you have any suggestion? I tried represent both cluster and corpus documents as tfidf matrices, but it seems hard to give desire result by computing similarity between two matrix. And I tried LSI, but it is the corpus I want to rank not the cluster documents which forces me to find the centroid representative of the cluster.

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: WoW, thanks a lot. I didn't think of cosine sim can be calculated like this.

Comment: You are very welcome! Happy days - a couple of lines of code can do things that would have taken a while to do in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np

cluster = ['Line a baking pan with a sheet of parchment paper.',
            'Line the cake pan with parchment paper.',
            'Line the bottom with parchment paper.',
            'Line a baking pan with parchment paper.']

corpus = ['Add vinegar and sugar.',
          'Remove pan from heat and let stand 5 minutes.',
          'Line the pan with parchment paper.']

# Train tfidf on cluster
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_cluster = tfidf.fit_transform(cluster)

# Tranform the corpus using the trained tfidf
tfidf_corpus = tfidf.transform(corpus)

# Cosine similarity
cos_similarity = np.dot(tfidf_corpus, tfidf_cluster.T).A
avg_similarity = np.mean(cos_similarity, axis=1)

cos_similarity
Out[271]: 
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.31452723, 0.36145869, 0.        , 0.43855558],
       [0.50673521, 0.8242027 , 0.7139548 , 0.70655744]])

avg_similarity
Out[272]: array([0.        , 0.27863537, 0.68786254])
```

Comment: My real corpus is quite large, and I want to use cluster as query to rank the corpus documents. The after-tfidf corpus could be extreme high dimensional so that I plan use LSA to reduce dimension. However, I encountered the problem which side to fit the LSA model. Since I want to use cluster to rank corpus and the TFIDF model is fit on cluster. I might need to fit LSA on cluster. But the cluster sometimes has only 2-3 dimensions which might suggest on the corpus side. Now! I think I am totally confused........

Comment: Your question stated that you wanted to compare each document in your corpus and the cluster. So, in the answer, tfidf is fit on the cluster and the corpus is then mapped (transformed) onto the cluster space. The transformed corpus has the same number of columns (words) as your cluster and the number of rows will correspond to the number of documents in your corpus. If you do the opposite, tfidf.fit on the corpus this will result in a tfidf with a much bigger number of columns (words) and the number of rows will again be equal to the number of documents. I don't see what the advantage is.